# Angular with lazy-loading in production

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, continuous-deployment

Is there any way to handle the case when a lazy loaded module is not available?

The case: user has a tab with a previous version of the app which uses hashed chunkes.
We deployed a new version.
User's version of app will try to fetch an old one, which is not available already, (new hash is 123123, prev hash 321321, so app will tries to fetch 321312 which is not available already)

We would like to reload the page in that case for user, any ideas if it's possible to handle such cases?

Comment: Not tested at all, but maybe you could subscribe to router events of type NavigationError.

Comment: have you tried canLoad guard